# What's the physical differences between server and client certificate?

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, client-certificates

I know their logical differences, their intended ways to use. What I want to know are, how both certificates differs in the procedure of generation, of their actual contents.

Suppose you'll generate a self-signed *some* certificate with following procedure:

1. generating a private CA certificate, assume that you've got "ca.crt".
2. generating a private key as `openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out key.pem -outform PEM`.
3. generating a CSR as `openssl req -new -key key.pem -keyform PEM -out req.pem -outform PEM`.
4. signing to the CSR as `openssl ca -in req.pem -out cert.pem -cert ca.crt -keyfile key.pem -keyform PEM`.

I searched the web a lot but I couldn't find out whether the procedure above and the contents of generated certificate get differed when I generate a server certificate and a client certificate.

Your answers are greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in the format. Both are X.509 certificates with the use-for-SSL bit set.

Comment: Then, how about the contents? Aren't any descriptions contained which tell this is a server certification or client certification? In other words, are server certifications and client certifacations exchangeable if I intendedly generate each with same distiguish name (dn)?

Comment: @TakaoIIZUKA No, because they *aren't* for server identification or client identification. They are to identify the *host* that sends them, regardless of how it is operating in any specific connection. You don't need more than one certificate for that purpose, unless you're doing virtual hosting of course.